# Multiple excel rows part of 1 json item: how to

Tags: javascript, html, json, excel, sheetjs

Introduction: Fetching datas from an automatic generated excel sheet to build an item barcode label using html/java.

I have a code that works pretty when it fetches simple row data from excel to json in html. Mostly thanks to the great community here.

```js
    // Method to upload a valid excel file
function upload() {
  var files = document.getElementById('file_upload').files;
  if(files.length==0){
    alert("Please choose any file...");
    return;
  }
  var filename = files[0].name;
  var extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".")).toUpperCase();
  if (extension == '.XLS' || extension == '.XLSX') {
      //Here calling another method to read excel file into json
      excelFileToJSON(files[0]);
  }else{
      alert("Please select a valid excel file.");
  }
}

//Method to read excel file and convert it into JSON 

function excelFileToJSON(file){
    try {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
      reader.onload = function(e) {

          var data = e.target.result;
          var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
              type : 'binary'
          });
          var result = {};
          var firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
          //reading only first sheet data
          var jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName]);
          //displaying the json result into HTML table
          displayJsonToHtmlTable(jsonData);
          }
      }catch(e){
          console.error(e);
      }
}

//Method to display the data in HTML Table
function displayJsonToHtmlTable(jsonData){
  var table=document.getElementById("display_excel_data");
  if(jsonData.length>0){
      var htmlData=''
      
      for(var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
          var row=jsonData[i];
          var itemname = row["Item Name"] || '';
          var codemedicament = row["Code Medicament"] || '';
          var price = row["Price"] || '';
          var sku = row["SKU"] || '';
          var din = row["Din"] || '';
          var npn = row["NPN"] || '';
          var suppliers = row["Suppliers"] || '';
          var upc = row["UPC"] || '';
          
          htmlData+='<table class="pagebreak box">'
           +'<tr><td class="itemname" colspan=3>'+itemname+'</td></tr>'
           +'<tr><td class="codemedicament" colspan=2><font class="octagon">'+codemedicament+'</font></td>'
           +'<td class="price">'+price+'&nbsp;</td></tr>'
           +'<tr><td class="sku">'+sku+'</td>'
           +'<td class="upc" colspan=2 rowspan=3><div class=upc><svg class="barcode" jsbarcode-format="upc" jsbarcode-value="'+upc+'" jsbarcode-height=26 jsbarcode-width="1" js-barcode-fontsize=1 jsbarcode-textmargin="2" jsbarcode-margin="0" jsbarcode-marginLeft="19"></svg></div></td></tr>'
           +'<tr><td class="din">'+din+npn+'</td></tr>'
           +'<tr><td class="suppliers">'+suppliers+'</td></tr>'   
           +'</table>';
      }
      table.innerHTML=htmlData;
      JsBarcode(".barcode").init();
  }else{
      table.innerHTML='There is no data in Excel';
  }
}
```

```css
 .table{
    border:solid 1px;
    //width: 50mm;
    //height: 30mm;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse:collapse; //in table css, collapse is equivalent to cellspacing in table css and paddling is :enabled in td
    padding:0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;
}

td {
    //border:solid 1px;
}

.itemname{
    //border:solid 1px;
    height: 10mm;
    width:  48mm;
    margin: 0mm;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:  3mm;
    line-height:    3mm;
    z-index:    1;
    padding-top:    0mm;
    padding-bottom: 0mm;
    padding-left:   1mm;
    padding-right:  1mm;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow:   hidden;
    max-width:  100%;
    max-height: 100%;   
}

.codemedicament{
    //border: solid black 1px;
    height: 8mm;
    width:  20mm;
    margin: 0mm;
    font-size: 2.0mm;
    font-family:"Arial";
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    padding-top:    0mm;
    padding-bottom: 0mm;
    padding-left:   1mm;
    padding-right:  0mm;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow:   hidden;
    max-width:  100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.price{
    //border: solid 1px;
    height: 8mm;
    width:  28mm;
    margin: 0mm;
    margin-right: 0mm;
    font-family:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:  1.5em;
    font-weight:    600;
    padding-top:    0mm;
    padding-bottom: 0mm;
    padding-left:   0mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow:   hidden;
    max-width:  100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.sku{
    //border:solid 1px;
    height: 4mm;
    width:  15mm;
    margin: 0mm;
    font-family:    times new roman;
    font-size:  2mm;
    color:  #1F272E;    
    overflow:   hidden;
    padding-top:    0mm;
    padding-bottom: 0mm;
    padding-left:   0mm;
    padding-right:  0mm;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width:  100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.din{
    //border:solid 1px;
    height: 3mm;
    width:  15mm;
    margin: 0mm;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:  1.8mm;
    letter-spacing: 0px;    
    padding-top:    0mm;
    padding-bottom: 0mm;
    padding-left:   0mm;
    padding-right:  0mm;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow:   hidden;
    max-width:  100%;
    max-height: 100%;    
}

.suppliers{
    //border:solid 1px;
    height: 5mm;
    width:  15mm;
    margin: 0mm;
    font-family:    times new roman;
    font-size:  2mm;
    line-height:    2mm;
    z-index:    1;  
    padding-top:    0mm;
    padding-bottom: 0mm;
    padding-left:   0mm;
    padding-right:  0mm;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow:   hidden;
    max-width:  100%;
    max-height: 100%;    
}

.upc{
    //border:solid 1px;
    height: 12mm;
    width:  33mm;
    margin: 0mm;
    font-family:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:  0.5em;      
    padding-top:    0mm;
    padding-bottom: 0mm;
    padding-left:   0mm;
    padding-right:  0mm;
    vertical-align: center;
    justify-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
    overflow:   hidden;
    max-width:  100%;
    max-height: 100%;
        
}

.codemedicament_word {
    width: 20mm;
    height: 8mm;
    padding:0mm;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size: 2.8mm;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    overflow: hidden;
} 
.octagon {
    width: 3mm;
    height: 3mm;
    background: lightgrey;
    clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0%, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    float:left
}

.box {
    --b: 1px;   /* thickness of the border */
    --c: #d1d8dd;   /* color of the border */
    --w: 6px;  /* length of border */
    width: fit-content;
    overflow: hidden;
  
    border: var(--b) solid #0000; /* space for the border */
    --_g: #0000 90deg,var(--c) 0;
    --_p: var(--w) var(--w) border-box no-repeat;
    background:
      conic-gradient(from 90deg  at top    var(--b) left  var(--b),var(--_g)) 0    0    / var(--_p),
      conic-gradient(from 180deg at top    var(--b) right var(--b),var(--_g)) 100% 0    / var(--_p),
      conic-gradient(from 0deg   at bottom var(--b) left  var(--b),var(--_g)) 0    100% / var(--_p),
      conic-gradient(from -90deg at bottom var(--b) right var(--b),var(--_g)) 100% 100% / var(--_p);
      border-collapse:collapse; //in table css, collapse is equivalent to cellspacing in table css and paddling is :enabled in td
      padding:0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;
  }

  .pagebreak {
    page-break-inside:avoid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.5/xlsx.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.5/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
 

<h1>Upload an excel file to display in HTML Table</h1>
<!-- Input element to upload an excel file -->
<input type="file" id="file_upload" />
<button onclick="upload()">Upload</button>  
<br>
<br>
<!-- table to display the excel data -->

<p style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p>

<div id="display_excel_data"></div>
```

The result from excel to html shows it perfectly well

[image]

==============================================

But the problem happens when some items contain multiple "Code Medicament" values in different rows. (see picture below) That means we can no longer set each row = each barcode.

Is there a way to have a label generated with the "multiple codes" for 1 item? (and if yes, is it possible to sort and display those codes in a pre-determined order list (for eg. order from left to right on the label as [P,B,C,X,H,D,A]

[image]

==========================================================

Current output with the script (not working):

[image]

If you can help by providing detailed instructions (especially where and what -the syntax in Javascript), it would really be appreciated.

Comment: @FiniteLooper Do you think what I plan to achieve is easier with Python/PHP over javascript?